# Where do conformal symmetry breaking and the gravitational constant come from in conformal theories of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, conformal-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

[Conformal gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_gravity) theories are alternatives to GR which are conformally invariant. That is, if $g_{\mu\nu}$ is a metric solving the field equations of the theory, then so is $\Omega^2 g_{\mu\nu}$ for any nonvanishing function ("conformal factor") $\Omega$. Some people study the possibility that such a theory might actually be the correct theory of gravity at long distances, with GR being incorrect. One reason to think this might be true is that typically, such theories can explain galactic rotation curves without invoking dark matter at all.

The obvious first objection, to me, when thinking about such a proposal, is the fact that the universe does *not* seem to be conformally invariant. After all, in a conformally invariant theory, "distances" or "proper times" are really a kind of "gauge-dependent" quantity, which could always be shifted by using a metric which differs by a conformal factor. But in the actual universe, "proper times" of particles *do* seem to be real physical quantities. For instance, the probability that an unstable particle will decay is dependent on its lifetime and the amount of proper time it experiences. So this leads to the question:

**Question 1:** In a conformal theory of gravity, what breaks the conformal symmetry -- why does the spacetime metric seem to be a real physical quantity? Is it the Higgs which does this?

As a related question, at least in Weyl conformal gravity in 3+1 dimensions the coupling constant between gravity and the other forces is dimensionless -- so the Newtonian constant $G$ is not absolute.

**Question 2:** In a conformal theory of gravity, where does the "effective constant" $G$ come from?

I suppose the answer to either question might be "it depends on the theory", in which case I'd really like to see somewhere where this is addressed for one such theory -- say for Weyl conformal gravity or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

The point about conformal gravity is that *vacuum* field equations are conformally invariant. This means that when you have a solution of the vacuum equations and apply a conformal transformation, you generate the metric of a *new* vacuum space-time obeying the field equations. However, physical observers in this *new* space-time will observe, e.g., different [tidal forces (geodesic deviation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation), since the Riemann curvature tensor is *not* invariant under conformal transforms and space-times are not generally Ricci flat in conformal gravity. In other words, there are quasi-local physical measurements that are able to distinguish between the space-times before and after the transform, and thus they are, physically, different space-times.

However, once massive fields are added to the action, the conformal symmetry of the equations is broken. In other words, if you take a non-vacuum space-time in conformal gravity with massive sources and apply a conformal transformation, you will get a space-time corresponding to *different*, possibly completely nonphysical matter sources.

Conventionally, one often talks about vacuum space-times which are vacua "almost everywhere", but the matter sources are still hidden in zero volumes as boundary conditions (e.g. black-holes"space-times, various "thin" disks and shells,...). The conformal transformation then turns the vacuum into vacuum, but almost always changes the meaning of the boundary conditions and thus of the matter source. (As an exercise, I recommend reading through Griffiths & Podolský *Exact Space-times* and finding out how many space-times can be conformally mapped onto the Einstein static universe.) In other words, the *physical meaning* of the space-time is generally changed by the conformal transformation.

You mentioned the Higgs' mechanism and it is, indeed, appropriate to mention it while talking about conformal gravity. The point is the Standard model has a conformal symmetry (the fields are massless) which is broken by spontaneous symmetry breaking (the fields become effectively massive). When you couple the Standard model to a conformal gravity, it has the same conformal symmetry, and this is broken by the SM fields becoming effectively massive. However, nothing special needs to happen in the gravity sector, it is really all about the mass generation in the source sector. To say at least, this is the *scenario* of how it should all work.

On the other hand, I should warn that conformal gravity has never been proven to be able to reproduce ordinary physics of the solar system, including not only the Newtonian $N$-body dynamics of the sun-planet-moon systems but also e.g. Mercury perihelion shifts, equivalence principle tests within the solar system and so on; post-Newtonian dynamics of binary pulsars, and others. In this sense trying too hard to assign physical interpretations to everything that appears in the theory may be futile, since *it well may be that the theory has no physical meaning at all*. In fact, the problem with the Newtonian limit of conformal gravity has been known since the end of the nineties, and nothing has really happened for decades now.

---

About $G$ "missing" in the action:

The Weyl-gravity term $\sim C^{\mu\nu\kappa\lambda}C_{\mu\nu\kappa\lambda}$ has the dimension of $1/L^4$ where $L$ is length, whereas the matter Lagrangian density is $\sim E/L^3 \sim m/L^3$ (suppressing $\sim c$ factors) where $m,E$ are mass, energy. As you have noted in the comments $[\hbar] = [E L]$ so one can write the coupling constant in the action as $(\hbar/\alpha) C^{\mu\nu\kappa\lambda}C_{\mu\nu\kappa\lambda}$ with $\alpha$ dimensionless and then it can be added to the matter part.

However, we still have to require that the theory has a Newtonian limit such that masses generate acceleration fields $\sim -\tilde{G}M/r^2$ in the weak-field Newtonian limit, such that $\tilde{G}$ is a factor that is generally quantitatively close to Newton's gravitational constant $G$ and $M$ is close to the dynamical mass of the object. Using only the constants appearing in the theory, it is obvious that in the emergence of the Newtonian limit there has to appear a new fundamental length scale $L_{\rm W}$ such that $\tilde{G} \propto L_{\rm W}^2/\hbar$. In other words, in the anticipation of the Newtonian limit, one could also write the coupling constant as $\hbar/\alpha = L_{\rm W}^2/G$. Picking between the two is just a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to digest this! For now, I'm confused by your unit count at the end. It seems to me that the units $1/L^4$ and $E/L^3$ differ by $E \cdot L$, the units of action (up to a $c$). But $\hbar$ is already a fundamental constant with units of action. So whatever the coupling constant between these two terms, you can view it either as introducing a _second_ fundamental unit of action, or (perhaps better) as just being some _unitless_ constant times $\hbar$. I don't see how anything like $G$ comes in, which ultimately introduces the Planck scale as a fundamental scale for all units.

Comment: @tcamps Sure, you use $\hbar$ instead of $G$. However, you will still need some symmetry-breaking constants (a mass scale) and $G$ would then be hidden in them to match actual observations.

Comment: It should be noted that this discussion is either way kind of academic, since the Newtonian limit of conformal gravity is not really resolved. In principle it is possible to build extended objects that will have $\sim - C /r$ external fields, and one can *assume* e.g. protons and neutrons have "internal" structure such that $C = G m_{p/n}$, $m_{p/n}$ being their dynamical mass. But this has never been actually proven to be the case. Also, the construction would obviously violate at least the strong equivalence principle possibly even the weak one, and we now have quite a few tests for those.

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph of the answer, it may be worth pointing out that although $C_{\mu\nu\kappa\lambda}$ is not conformally invariant, if you raise one index to get ${C^\mu}_{\nu\kappa\lambda}$, you _do_ get something conformally invariant. But I don't really follow the discussion in this paragraph (e.g. why are you talking about the Riemann curvature tensor in the context of conformal gravity?) so perhaps this point is not important.

Comment: I still don't understand how $G$ emerges in your account -- from what I understand, wouldn't it only ever appear in any physical quantity as part of the ratio $L_W^2 / G$? So it seems like all this does is to introduce a clunky name "$L_W^2 / G$" for a single constant.

Comment: Perhaps I just need to understand the Higgs mechanism better -- but I'm pessimistic about this because all standard accounts of the Higgs mechanism assume a fixed background metric, and so presumably some adaptation of the story is needed to explain how the mechanism singles out one metric from a conformal class.

Comment: @tcamps The point with keeping $G$ in there is that in the end you need an emergent gravity where the acceleration caused by a mass has to have the leading contribution $-GM/r^2$ on some intermediate scale, where $M$ is close to the dynamical mass of the object. Of course, you can just make the emergent acceleration into the clunky expression $(L_{\rm W}^2/\hbar) M/r^2$ by replacing $L_{W}^2/G$ with just $\hbar$. The Riemann tensor appears in the [geodesic deviation equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation) and thus also the physical tidal force you can measure locally.

Comment: @tcamps My point is that conformal gravities (specifically Mannheim/Weyl conformal gravity) are *conjectured* to amount to physical theories. The fact that you run into contradictions only points to the fact that the program of reproducing e.g. solar-system physics (including the corresponding post-Newtonian corrections and equivalence principle tests) from conformal gravity has not been carried out and perhaps *cannot* be carried out. I should add an edit to that effect to the post.

Comment: Thanks for your good-faith attempts to explain things. I have awarded the bounty to you as time was running out. But I've refrained from "accepting", in hopes that perhaps somebody can shed some more light on the situation. In light of your comment beginning "It should be noted that this discussion is either way kind of academic", I take it that the actual mathematics of conformal gravity are not well-understood. In this respect, ChiralAnomaly's comment above about Maldacena's work seems relevant to extracting an Einsteinian limit, and _a fortiori_ a Newtonian limit.

Comment: Anyway, every vacuum solution to Einstein gravity is in particular a vacuum solution to conformal gravity. And all of the precision tests of Einstein gravity you invoke in the paragraph beginning "On the other hand..." (except perhaps the tests of the equivalence principle) reduce to effective point masses in a vacuum. So I'm not convinced that any of these provide evidence against conformal gravity. It seems to me that to differentiate the theories, one needs to study non-vacuum situations. Perhaps cosmology (e.g. Planck data) could better say something about this.

Comment: @tcamps True Einstein vacua (i.e. with no distributional sources of matter and no "massive" singularities) are mostly just "backgrounds" of the type od Minkowski and (A)dS space-times, and source-less gravitational waves (gravitational waves sourced by boundary conditions at infinity). The solar system or binary pulsars are not vacua (and not one made of point masses!), and the matter-gravity coupling is important. What I was saying is that conformal gravity coupled to a matter Lagrangian was never demonstrated to reproduce the Newtonian limit in the sense of the solar system. That is a fact.

Comment: Are you saying that standard solar system dynamics calculations do anything other than treating planets and the sun as point masses? And that binary pulsar calculations do anything other than treat their gravitational sources as point masses? That's news to me, though I am far from an expert. Your assertion that a Newtonian limit of conformal gravity plus a matter sector has not been demonstrated is well-taken -- my impression was that Maldacena's work alluded to above had somehow done exactly this, but I don't really understand that work, so probably I was mistaken.